# Scipy Newton-CG not accepting my hessian matrix?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm running a minimisation routine and I'm struggling to get Newton-CG to accept my hessian matrix. The hessian was calculated using numdifftools.Hessdiag

I define the function to be minimized;

```
def energy(x0, L, N, U, t, mu):

    mu = mu.reshape(L, L, N)
    x0 = x0.reshape(L, L, N, 2)
    ff = x0[:, :, :, 0] + 1j*x0[:, :, :, 1]

    nn = np.array(range(N))  # [0, 1, ..., N-1]
    norm = np.zeros((L,L))

    for i_x in range(0,L):
        for i_y in range(0,L):
            norm[i_x,i_y] = np.sum(np.abs(ff[i_x,i_y,:])**2)
    norm = np.repeat(norm, N)
    norm = norm.reshape(L, L, N)

    E = np.abs(np.sum((np.abs(ff)**2/norm * (U*nn*(nn-1)/2 - mu*nn))))

    return E
```

And then calculate the Hessian matrix for the minimization routine. If I print the hessian matrix for some given coordinates it evaluates like I'd hoped.

```
Hfun = nd.Hessdiag(energy)
x0 = np.tile(guess, (L,L,1,1))
x0 = x0.reshape(L*L*N*2)

print Hfun(x0, L, N, U, t, mu)

x_min = scipy.optimize.minimize(energy, x0, method='Newton-CG', jac=energy_grad, hess=Hfun, args=(L, N, U, t, mu))
```

The minimization routine gives me a value error though (I've checked the jacobian is fine).

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What is an example of `guess`, `L`, and `N` that returns the error?

Comment: L=5, N=3, and the guess could be anything, right now it's just a uniform array of ones eg.  guess = np.ones(N*2)      (I would post the jacobian too but it's quite a long expression)

Comment: At least tell us *how* the Jacobian was computed. Using numdifftools? Or manually? What makes you think the Hessian's to blame? Does it work if you remove it from `minimize`? And could you add sample parameters `L,N,U,t,mu` for reproducibility?

Comment: I don't have `numdifftools` installed at the moment, so I can't check this myself.  Why do you use `nd.Hessdiag`?  Have you tried `nd.Hessian`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, my Jacobian was manually calculated and the minimize routine works with it alone. The Hessian computes fine on its own (I was using nd.Hessdiag after seeing an example minimization problem but nd.Hessian was right for me thanks).